# Guess random number hot and cold game output

Tags: c, random, codeblocks

Trying to build a program in code blocks c language that:

1. Generates a random secret number from `1 to 100` and asks user to guess that number.
2. If user guesses correctly prints guess is correct.
3. For the first guess if it is not correct it should say hot.
4. Tells the user he is getting hot if his guesses are getting closer to the secret.
5. Or cold if his guesses are further away.
6. Game continues until secret number is guessed.

My current program is giving incorrect output on whether the guess is hot or cold also not sure on where I should place `(` vs `{` if any at all or where to use `"if"` vs `"else if"`. If not too much please explain changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_VAL 100

 int main(void)
{
  int next_guess, first_guess, secret, distance;
  srand(time(0));

  secret = 1 + rand()%MAX_VAL;
  distance = (secret - first_guess);

while (first_guess != secret) {
printf(" enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
scanf("%d", &first_guess);

{

if (first_guess == secret)
    printf("You guessed correctly!\n");

if (first_guess != secret)
    printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
    scanf("%d", &next_guess);

if (next_guess == secret)
    printf("You guessed correctly!\n");

if ((next_guess-secret) < distance)
    printf("Your guess was hot,");

if ((next_guess-secret) >= distance)
     printf("Your guess was cold,");

   }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `first_guess` before using it in the while loop.

Comment: @Jayesh It isn't a complete answer, just a comment.

Comment: while you get correct number you should use `break;` to get out of the loop.

Comment: @Jayesh It likely isn't the only problem and I am not interested in debugging it.  You can if you like.

Comment: @RetiredNinja when u say i should initialize what do you mean? I am new to programming.

Comment: @user3723557 Assign it a value like you do with `secret` and `distance`, otherwise it could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, there are a few things you need to know:
first you need to compare between the absolute value of the distances between the numbers because when you substract to get the distance you could get a negative number.

`while (first_guess != secret)`
second you shouldn't compare a value that you don't have read already.

There is no need to put the `{}` outside the `IF`s, you need to use it after the `if` sentence. Also try to improve your indentation a little bit.

And last, the most important advice, answering to your question is if you have an `if` that checks some condition, you don't need to put another `if` to check the opossite condition if just two conditions are posibble, just use an `else` and if needed use anothers `if else` inside the first `else`.

example:

the wrong way:

```
if (first_guess == secret)
    printf("You guessed correctly!\n");

if (first_guess != secret) {
    printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
    scanf("%d", &next_guess);
}

right way:

if (first_guess == secret)
    printf("You guessed correctly!\n");

else {
    printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
    scanf("%d", &next_guess);
}
```

A solution will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_VAL 100

#define ABSOLUTE(a) (((a)>0)?(a):(-a))

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int secret,new,newdistance,olddistance,ok;
    secret = 1 + rand()%MAX_VAL;
    printf ("secret is %d",secret);
    char clean;  
    do {
        printf(" enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
        ok=scanf ("%d",&new);
        while ((clean=getchar())!='\n');
    } while(ok!=1);
    newdistance = (secret - new);
    do {
        if (new == secret)
        printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
        else {
            do {
                printf("enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
                ok=scanf ("%d",&new);
                while ((clean=getchar())!='\n');
            } while(ok!=1);
            if (new == secret)
                printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
            else {
                olddistance=newdistance;
                newdistance=secret-new;
                if (ABSOLUTE(newdistance) < ABSOLUTE(olddistance))
                    printf("Your guess was hot,");
                else
                    printf("Your guess was cold,");
            }
        }
    } while (new!= secret);
    return (0);
}
```

I added the line `while ((clean=getchar())!='\n');` to make sure every input from the user will be correctly readed.

If the macro is causing you problems here is an implementation that uses a function to calculate the absolute value instead of a macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_VAL 100


int absolute (int a) {
    return (a>0?a:-a);  
}


int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int secret,new,newdistance,olddistance,ok,flagfirstguess;
    flagfirstguess=1;
    secret = 1 + rand()%MAX_VAL;
    printf ("secret is %d",secret);
    char clean;  
    do {
        printf(" enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
        ok=scanf ("%d",&new);
        while ((clean=getchar())!='\n');
    } while(ok!=1);
    newdistance = (secret - new);
    do {
        if (new == secret)
            printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
        else {
            if (flagfirstguess==1) {
                printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
                flagfirstguess=0;
            }
            else {
                do {
                    printf("enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
                    ok=scanf ("%d",&new);
                    while ((clean=getchar())!='\n');
                } while(ok!=1);
                if (new == secret)
                    printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
                else {
                    olddistance=newdistance;
                    newdistance=secret-new;
                    if (absolute(newdistance) < absolute(olddistance))
                        printf("Your guess was hot,");
                    else
                        printf("Your guess was cold,");
                }
            }
        }
    } while (new!= secret);
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run. line 5 error expected expression before '/' token

Comment: @user3723557 try deleting the comment maybe  codeblocks with the settings you are trying to compile doesn't allow comments with `//` I edited it in the post.

Comment: also added another implementation of the solution that doesn't use the absolute value macro

Comment: psycho Thanks for your help, love the 1 without the absolute value macro. Only 1 slight problem on the 1st guess if not correct it should say hot.

Comment: @user3723557 here you have, you made me think a little bit, but I think wit a flag it will work

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. Really appreciate you putting so much time in this!

Answer (score 1):

your code

```
if (first_guess != secret)
  printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", 
    MAX_VAL);
  scanf("%d", &next_guess);
```

does not do what you think it does, the if-statement will only affect the printf-statement and not the scanf statement. You should enclose the statements in braces

```
if (first_guess != secret)
{
  printf("Your guess was hot enter your next guess from (1 to %d)?\n", 
    MAX_VAL);
  scanf("%d", &next_guess);
}
```

I am no fan of scanf() for keyboard input so I would instead use fgets() where you specify the max size buffer and then convert the value to an integer alternatively use sscanf() to convert

```
char buffer[32];
fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
next_guess = atoi( buffer ); 

or

char buffer[32];
fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
sscanf( buffer, "%d", &next_guess );
```

You should always initialize all variables in C

```
int next_guess = 0, first_guess = 0, secret, distance = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need two guess for this game. This would be my version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_VAL 100

int main(void)
{
    int guess, secret, distance;
    srand(time(0));

    secret = 1 + rand()%MAX_VAL;

    while (true) 
    {
        printf(" enter your guess from (1 to %d)?\n", MAX_VAL);
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if (guess == secret)
        {
            printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            distance = guess-secret;

            if (distance>0)
                printf("Your guess was hot,");

            else
                printf("Your guess was cold,");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it still gives incorrect hot or cold output as distance may end up being a negative number and you can move closer while its a negative but get cold because, `distance>0` only works if `distance = guess - secret` is positive. That is why I originally had 2 guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example I Tried last year

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h" 
#include "time.h"

int main(void)
{
    int n,a,count=0,l,score=0;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        count=0;
        srand(time(NULL));
        a=rand()%100+1; //RANGE OF NUMBER, here it is 1 to 100
        printf("Select  Level\n");
        printf("1)Easy\n");
        printf("2)Medium\n");
        printf("3)Hard\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==1)
            l=20;
        else if(n==2)
            l=10;
        else
            l=6;
        printf("Enter a number between 1 to 100\n");
        while(count!=l)
        {
            scanf("%d",&n);
            //system("cls");
            if(n==a)
            {
                printf("\nYou win...!!!\n %d is the Correct Number.",n);
                break;
            }
            else if(n>a)
            {
                printf("\n%d is Too High...!!!",n);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n%d is Too Low...!!!",n);
                count++;
            }
            if(count==l)
            {
                printf("\nCorrect Number is %d\n",a);
                break;
            }
            printf("\nYou have %d chance left.\n",l-count); 
        }
        printf("Do You Want To Play More ... (Press y)");
        ch=getch();
    }
    while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```